# Shorten jQuery Multiple If Statements

Tags: jquery

I have three jQuery functions that include an if/else if statement. Basically each different function toggles/removes a different css class depending on if the window width is less than or greater than than a certain value.

All the functions are *very* similar and I have been trying to shorten them/combine them into one function. I'm pretty sure it can be shortened quite easily, but I can't figure out how!

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() > 670) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen'))) {
        $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen');
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 670) {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen');
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen');
    }
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() < 670) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen2'))) {
        $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen2');
    }
    else if ($(window).width() < 670) {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen2');
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen2');
    }
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() < 540) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen3'))) {
        $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen3');
    }
    else if ($(window).width() < 540) {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen3');
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen3');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain all the functionality I had to create a function that took 3 variables:

```
function image(condition, windowWidth, css) {
    return function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    var windowCondition = condition($(window).width(), windowWidth);
        if (windowCondition && ($(this).hasClass(css))) {
        $(this).removeClass(css);
        } 
        else if (windowCondition) {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass(css);
        $(this).addClass(css);
        }
    }
}   

var lessThan = function(a, b) { return a < b; };
var greaterThan = function(a, b) { return a > b; };

var func1 = image(greaterThan, 669, 'exampleimgopen');
var func2 = image(lessThan, 670, 'exampleimgopen2');
var func3 = image(lessThan, 540, 'exampleimgopen3');

$('.exampleimg').click(func1);
$('.exampleimg' ).click(func2);
$('.exampleimg').click(func3);
```

And also create two variables to manage the less than and greater than 670px

The just call the functions for every class on click

Answer (score 1):

use binding function for main class then make your conditions similar to previous function. example: $('.mainClass').bind()

Answer (score 1):

Shorten format of your jQuery code should be

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {

        $('.about').hide(600);

        screenwidth= var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var classname="exampleimgopen";
        if(screenwidth<670){ classname = "exampleimgopen2"; };
        else if(screenwidth<540){ classname = "exampleimgopen3"; };

        $(this).toggleClass(classname);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes two arguments: width & class name.

```
function YourFunc(width, className)
{
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    $('.about').hide(600);

    if (windowWidth < width && $(this).hasClass(className)) {
        $(this).removeClass(className);
    }
    else if (windowWidth < width) {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass(className);
        $(this).addClass(className);
    }
}
```

And invoke this function wherever you need it and pass the relevant arguments.